# How to add more columns and also change the table name in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi I have a model or table called bluedarts but I want to change the name to "staging" and also add couples of columns to the same table. Whats the command to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations would be the answer here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html. You will need the rename_table method.

```
rails g migration rename_bluedarts_to_staging


def change
  rename_table :bluedarts, :staging
end
```

Then specify in the model that needs to use this table that it needs to use the staging table:

```
set_table_name 'staging'
```

To add the columns, create another migration for each column.

```
rails g migration add_column_name_to_staging column_name:string
```

The column_name:string bit says what the column name should be, and what type it should be. Then you just run `rake db:migrate`. Because of the naming convention used in the migration, it knows what code to use to add the column properly.